# Table partitioning column selection

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have an invoice model that we want to partition. As a basic example, this consists of:

## Table: InvoiceHeads

Column: HeaderId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NONCLUSTERED UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY

Column: InvoiceDate DATETIME

Column: MemberId INT CLUSTERED INDEX

Column: SupplierId

## Table: InvoiceLines

Column: LineId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NONCLUSTERED UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY

Column: HeaderId INT CLUSTERED INDEX (Foreign key constraint TO InvoiceHeads)

Partitioning the InvoiceHeads table is straight forward, we would do it on InvoiceDate but the tables are generally joined in queries by the HeaderID column.

Does this mean for partitioning to be as effective as possibly on both we should partition InvoiceLines on HeaderId with ranges that most closely match how their parent InvoiceHeads are partitioned i.e.

1-100000 (roughly invoice dates for year 2017)
1000001-200000 (roughly invoice dates for year 2018)
200000+ (roughly will be current year)

If that is the right approach we would then have to maintain the partition yearly to alter the ranges to create a new one for the year just past.

I am also under the impression if we switch on auto create incremental statistics along with auto update statistics, the 20% changes that trigger the auto update will be specific to the volume in each partition then so will have more chance of keeping our current year stats as up to date as possible without if if having to do a fullscan on unchanged previous years data.

Comment: You could de-normalize your tables by copying the InvoiceDate also in the InvoiceLines table.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about doing this to ensure they all get partitioned the same I was just interested if there would be a greater performance gain if I partitioned the InvoiceLines table by HeaderId when the criteria for the InvoiceHeads table was on invoicedate and the join, so criteria for locating the InvoiceLines is on the headerid.

Be interested to know if anyone has done it this way, may just have to be a try it and see what the query plans and i/o stats produce both ways.

Comment: Does appear that creating the partition field on the InvoiceLines table by holding the InvoiceDate against each record should do the trick and rebuild clustered and non clustered indexes on the partition scheme